# How to Improve Assignment Code in Node.js (ES6 style)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6, mongoose-schema

Is there any way to improve this code? Using ES6 style i am using latest stable version of node.js.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
date: string;
dateObj: {
    year: number,
    month: number,
    day: number
};
project: string;
task: string;
hours: number;
});

let data = new Data();
data.date = new Date(body.date);
    data.dateObj = {
        year: body.dateObj.year,
        month: body.dateObj.month,
        day: body.dateObj.day
    }
    data.project = body.project;
    data.task = body.task;
    data.hours = body.hours;
}
```

Comment: what is `Data`? please add the missing parts as well.

Comment: If you're asking for help improving working code, this may be a better fit over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but be sure to take their [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read their [help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) first, particularly [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Side note: Just FYI, while "[assignation](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/assignation)" is an English word, it's not the one you want there. :-) (An "assignation" is a secret meeting, typically a lovers get-together.) You probably want "assignment" there.

Comment: @NinaScholz Data is mongoose schema

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Possibly not, lots of mentions of the body object ;-)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - I mostly try to avoid objectifying bodies. ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @NinaScholz i have updated the question now you can see what is Data,

Comment: There's no relation between Data and UserSchema. Is it a model? Please, add the clarification and relevant tags (mongoose?) to the question.

Comment: @estus yes it is mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that `Data` is Mongoose model, properties can be picked from an object and assigned to model instance through constructor [`document` argument](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model):

```
const date = new Date(body.date);
const { year, month, day } = body.dateObj;
const { project, task, hours } = body;

let data = new Data({
  date,
  dateObj: { year, month, day },
  project, task, hours 
});
```

Picking `body.dateObj` properties may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of es6 constructs like destructuring and spread. Take a look at following snippet.

```
let data = new Data();
const {date, dateObj, project, task, hours} = body;
data = {
    date: new Date(date),
    dateObj: {...dateObj},
    project,
    task,
    hours
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    let data = Object.assign({},
    { dateObj:{
          year: body.dateObj.year,
          month: body.dateObj.month,
          day: body.dateObj.day
         }, 
     project: body.project,
     task: body.task,
     hours: body.hours,
     new Data() 
    })
```

You can use object.assign

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and more importantly, *why*.